# It is possible to save only the viewport to a file in plplot?

Tags: fortran, plplot

I want to write only the viewport (red border) and its content into a eps file. Is that possible? Furthermore, the unit of the created eps file is "pt" but I want "mm".

My Code:

```
  use :: plplot

  implicit none

  integer(4)        :: i_dummy

  real(8)               :: xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax

  real(8), dimension(5) :: x
  real(8), dimension(5) :: y

  character(len=80)     :: output_file_name

! set name of output file
  output_file_name = 'test_output.eps'
  call plsfnam(output_file_name)

! set plot device
  call plsdev('epscairo')
  i_dummy = plsetopt('geometry','210x297')

! set background color
  call plscolbg(255,255,255)    

! init
  call plinit()     

! set environment
  xmin = 0.0d0
  xmax = 210.0d0
  ymin = 0.0d0
  ymax = 297.0d0
  call plenv( xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, 1, -1)

  x(1) = 0.0d0
  y(1) = 0.0d0

  x(2) = 105.0d0
  y(2) = 147.0d0

  x(3) = 210.0d0
  y(3) = 297.0d0

! set colour
  call plcol0( 9 )

! set line width
  call plwidth( 2.0d0 )

! set line style
  call pllsty( 2 )

! draw lines
  call plline( x, y )

! end
  call plend()

end program test_plplot
```

I get this file. There is the red section i want but with a white border and the unit is "pt":

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but the plplot subroutines are defined with specific kind constants for their argument. Using literal constants 4 and 8 is not only not portable in general, but may easily become incompatible with the plplot definition if you change your compiler or some compiler options. Integers in plplot should be the default integers (which do not have to be kind 4) and the reals should be kind `plflt`.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you, good to know!